# NSButton делегат

Tags: cocoa, macos, objective-c

Привет. Есть View-based NSTableView у которой строки состоят из NSView. На NSView есть некоторые компоненты интерфейса - label, image и т.д., но есть еще NSButton. Как получить нажатие на кнопку из главного класса (например с AppDelegate)? Читал что это можно сделать как через делегат, так и через дополнительный класс. Т.е. вопрос состоит в том "Какое решение будет правильней?". Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оч простой и не правильный вариант - использовать NSNotificationCenter. Подписывемся в апп делегате, постим в другом и все ок.

Вроде как самый верный спосов - добавить таргетом на экшн прямо апп делегат, что-то типа

`[myButton addTarget:[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate action:@selector(myButtonDidPress:)];` 
не уверен как этот метод точно выглядит в макоси.

Делегат и блок - 2 равноправных и верных друга для решения таких задач, можно использовть их, лично я предпочел бы блок.

**Делегат:**

все в вашем решении выглядит правильно, единственное, делегат всегда передает себя, это как само собой разумеющееся, обязательно делай это, потом проблем не будет. То есть

```
@protocol ButtonClickerDelegate <NSObject>

// если хочешь. чтоб компилятор ругался если ты забыл метод в делегате, пишем
@requed // если без него, вроде по умолчанию, если не ошибаюсь, @optional
дальше метод

- (void)clickedButton:(UIButton *)button inViewController:(UIViewController *)sender;

@end
```

дальше добавляем в свой заголочный файл `UIViewController`

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <ButtonClickerDelegate> clickerDelegate;
```

потом вызов метода:

```
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender {
    if ([self.clickerDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(clickedButton:inViewController:)]) {
        [self.clickerDelegate clickedButton:sender inViewController:self];
    }
}
```

и где-то, скажем во viewWillAppear собственно сетим делегат:

```
MYAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MYAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
self.clickedDelegate = appDelegate;
```

дальше в `MYAppDelegate.h` указываем, что он поддерживает протокол `<ButtonClickerDelegate>`

и в .m файле реализуем, собсвенно, метод делегата

```
- (void)clickedButton:(UIButton *)button inViewController:(UIViewController *)vc
{
     NSLog(@"BUTTON:%@ DID PRESS IN VIEW CONTROLLER:%@", button, vc);
}
```

но еще один момент мне не понятен совсем, если хочется, чтобы AppDelegate сделал что-то по нажатию на кнопку в UIViewController, почему не сделать просто:

```
- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender {
    MYAppDelegate *appDelegate = (MYAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [appDelegate doSomethingWithPressedButton];    
}
```

**ведь AppDelegate доступен из любого места в приложении, либо в Mac OS все не так?**

Comment: Спасибо большое. Использовал последний код. Работает. Но теперь смотрю что все-таки я не правильно многое организовал. Мне теперь нужно узнать индекс строки на которой эта кнопка нажата. Короче буду разбираться как сделать "правильней". Учится-учится и еще раз учится. Вам Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Пробовал через делегат, но не работает. Может неправильно делаю.

Добавил протокол:

```
@protocol ButtonControllerProtocol <NSObject>
- (void) viewButtonClicked;
@end
```

В ViewController.h:

@property (nonatomic, assign) id <ButtonControllerProtocol> buttonClickDelegate;

В ViewController.m:

```
- (IBAction)buttonInfo:(id)sender {
    [self.buttonClickDelegate viewButtonClicked];
    NSLog(@"clickView");
}
```

В AppDelegate.h прописал делегат < ButtonControllerProtocol >

В AppDelegate.m: добавил метод

```
- (void)viewButtonClicked {
    NSLog(@"clickDelegate");
}
```

Пока что "таргет" не прописывал. Почему сделал так: видел пример у которого две вьюхи и на каждой вьюхе по кнопке. через делегаты нажатие на эти кнопки обрабатываются. Но это на айОС.

Comment: я дополнил свой ответ, посмотрите